# Cannot find module './components/Table/Table' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to import a component as I have done like the other ones above it, but getting this error.

[image]

Comment: hm, do you have 2 Table folders in the same folder? Maybe some letters were from different alphabet and you are referencing to a wrong Table folder?

Comment: So I didn't notice that at first, but I deleted the duplicate folder and it still throws the same warning. Typescript has been very temperamental today, was even complaining when I was trying to import the css file. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a trailing space in the table folder name.